# How to change smart object outlines and colors?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I was wondering if there is a way to alter the color of the Smart object that has been inputted into Photoshop. Basically, I have a series of glyphs that need  to be altered so they  have new hexadecimal's. Is there an easy way to do this? There doesn't seem to be any Photoshop functions available?

Answer (score 9):

Highlight the Smart Object in the Layers Panel.

Choose Layer > Layer Style > Color Overlay.
Set the color overly blend mode to "Normal" and 100%.

Click the little color box, input your hex value, and click OK twice.

Comment: In addition, with this method you can copy the layerstyle and paste it to other smart object layers. Making recoloring of large iconsets very easy.

Comment: @KMSTR With Photoshop CS6 it's **even easier** if you apply the layer style to a Layer Group (folder) in the Layers Panel, then you can just drag layers into the group and they are instantly colored.

Comment: Sounds good. I will try that once I get my hands on CS6. I only tried the demo. What dissapointed me was that I couldn't use shapes in combination with fill and gradient layers anymore. I suppose thats done in the same way as applying layer styles now?

Comment: Sure you can. In fact they are better in CS6 because they are true vector layers. Control bar has a fill and stroke option similar to how you'd fill and stroke in Illustrator.

Comment: Perfect. thank you so much that was simple and effective.

Answer (score 1):

For # smart object outlines and colors?
  -- Ctrl + Click the particular smart object layer.
  -- The outer layout is selected
  -- Now right click or choose form EDIT menu > Stroke and give the color and stroke type.
  ** make this stroke things in separate layer so that u can change color later thr blending   option